# how to use route for delete record by URL?

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

I want to delete my data on database via JSON, and I'm using codeigniter framework

**My `route.php`**

```
$route['api/mahasiswa/delete/(:any)']['DELETE'] = 'MahasiswaController/deleteMahasiswa/$1';
```

**My controller**

```
  public function deleteMahasiswa($id)

$this->Mahasiswa->deleteMahasiswa($id);

$response = array(
  'Success' => true,
  'Info' => 'Data Berhasil di hapus');

$this->output
  ->set_status_header(200)
  ->set_content_type('application/json', 'utf-8')
  ->set_output(json_encode($response, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT))
  ->_display();
  exit;
```

**My model**

```
public function deleteMahasiswa($id)

$val = array(
  'id' => $id
);
$this->db->delete('mahasiswa', $val);
```

And I tried to access

```
http://localhost/json/public/api/mahasiswa/delete/6
```

But it didn't work

---

but my get data is work

my route

```
$route['api/mahasiswa/get/(:num)/(:num)']['GET'] = 'MahasiswaController/getMahasiswa/$1/$2';
```

my controller

```
  public function getMahasiswa($page, $size)
```

{

```
$response = array(
  'content' => $this->Mahasiswa->getMahasiswa(($page - 1) * $size, $size)->result(),
  'totalPages' => ceil($this->Mahasiswa->getCountMahasiswa() / $size));

$this->output
  ->set_status_header(200)
  ->set_content_type('application/json', 'utf-8')
  ->set_output(json_encode($response, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT))
  ->_display();
  exit;
```

}

my model

```
  public function getCountMahasiswa()

  return $this->db->count_all_results('t_akun', FALSE);
```

public function getMahasiswa($page, $size)

```
  return $this->db->get('t_akun', $size, $page);
```

and i use URL like this

http://localhost/json/public/api/mahasiswa/get/1/5/

[get data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AUrAO.png)

Comment: thanks for fixed my grammar :D

Comment: ^^ *fixing my grammar :-D

Answer (score 3):

Try dropping the `http` word

**In `route.php`**

```
$route['api/mahasiswa/delete/(:any)'] = 'MahasiswaController/deleteMahasiswa/$1';
```

In the controller

```
public function deleteMahasiswa($id)
{
    $this->Mahasiswa->deleteMahasiswa($id);

    $response = array('Success' => true, 'Info' => 'Data Berhasil di hapus');

    echo json_encode($response, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
}
```

If this function is being called through a javascript AJAX routine then the route setting is not needed. Why bother with a pretty URL that will never be seen in the browser?

The URL you tried to access

```
http://localhost/json/public/api/mahasiswa/delete/6
```

Indicates you are using a file organization way different than the typical (and recommend) Codeigniter structure. You can try changing your route to

```
$route['/json/public/api/mahasiswa/delete/(:any)'] = 'MahasiswaController/deleteMahasiswa/$1';
```

and see what happens.

The `/(:any)` is a wild card that connects to the `/$1` at the end of the statement. Basically is says "Take whatever comes after the last slash and replace the $1 with that value".

Comment: i dont know how to execute that code

i triend to access with

http://localhost/json/public/api/mahasiswa/delete/16

still not working :(

Comment: i dont know how to use (:any)  :(

can you give example for URL execution ?

Comment: youur code and my code hehe :D

i just confused how to execute (:any)

Comment: I just looked more carefully at the URL in your question. I will update my answer.

Comment: ok ty, check also my show data, it work, but my delete data still not work :(

Comment: Are you certain your server is setup to accept DELETE calls? It requires some very specific setup be in place before it will work on most servers. PUT calls have the same requirement. GET and POST on the other hand work without special settings